# Does a Globe of Invulnerability move with the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, area-of-effect

The *globe of invulnerability* spell creates "A barrier with a 10-foot radius [that] surrounds you".

Does that barrier move with the caster, or stays in the same place for the duration regardless of whether the caster moves afterwards?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## No.

The globe is not mobile.

From description of *[globe of invulnerability](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Globe%20of%20Invulnerability#content)*:

> An **immobile**, faintly shimmering barrier springs into existence in a 10-foot radius around you and remains for the duration.

Definition of [immobile](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/immobile):

> 1. Not moving; motionless.
>
>    1.1 Incapable of moving or being moved.

Comment: oh... The place where I was reading the spell did not have that word. I suppose your source is the PHB itself.

Comment: I run into that sometimes as well especially when just reading the google search result excerpts for quick reference..

Comment: Immobile with respect to what? The ground or the creature?

Comment: @illustro in general, the ground is not considered to be mobile while creatures are.

Answer (score 1):

The globe stays immobile sure, but you have to specify in respect to what, since it's cast on *self*, and specifically mentions that it shimmers into existence "around you". This implies that the point of reference is clearly the caster.

Now RAI, I think it's in reference to the earth, but RAW I don't think that's a solid argument to make since doing so requires the earth to be somehow special, which is just a vain human preconception and special pleading.

Other spells specify that they remain centered on you for the duration, however, which enforces the RAI reading.

---

I would argue that [Gcl's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/128692/22566) is unsatisfying, since movement is relative.

In his example, the sphere still moves in relation to the sun, to you, to the galaxy, to literally everything in the universe except arbitrarily, the earth.

Comment: In a fantasy setting that's different from reality, it could very well be the case where the Material Plane is stationary and the sun orbits it. I know logic and science don't agree, but there's literal magic affecting the world, so unless it's ever explicitly stated, assume the point of casting is stationary.

Comment: If you would list two or three other spells that "remain centered on you for the duration" it would be helpful as a way to support your answer.  Welcome to RPGSE. The [tour] and the [help] explain how this isn't a forum or a reddit.  The idea at a Q&A site is to answer the question as asked; if you want to address the shortcomings of another answer, that is a supplement to the answer you have to the question. (I thus edited your answer to slide your disagreement with the other answer after the answer you gave to the question as asked.)

Comment: Questioning what it is (im)mobile relative to is insightful.  Whenever something starts getting physics-y it is good to keep in mind that [D&D is not a physics engine](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/805200627089358848?lang=en)

Answer (score -2):

Hm it says that the barrier is immobile. But not IMMOVABLE (like the rod). So in theory as it is a GLOBE you could run around pushing the barrier with you. Like a rodent in a ball.

The barrier doesn't move of its own accord (immobile ie static, like a table or a desk) but it could be moved (movable ie not fixed in place, but could be pushed/carried) assuming you cast it in such a way that the globe is not half buried within the ground?

I dont actually think that's how the spell works but the theory is still there.

Comment: Hi, we are a Q&A site not a traditional forum (take the [tour] to learn more). As such, we expect answers to be fully answering the question, not just be related musings on the topic. If you can [edit] your answer to be a full answer, that's great! Otherwise, it may get deleted as a non-answer.

Comment: Do you have anything to support this idea? Anything that says it even has a physical surface that can be acted upon by somebody in the sphere?